# ProxyPassReverse not setting response header

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, tomcat, jenkins

I have an apache server sitting between a Jenkins server running on `127.0.0.1:8090` and the client browser.

I am giving `http://123.45.67.89/jenkins` in the browser and expecting the Jenkins to be redirected to `http://123.45.67.89/jenkins/login` page but instead, I am redirected to `http://123.45.67.89/login` page.

In the apache `httpd.conf` I tried giving the `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse`

```
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
ProxyPass /jenkins http://127.0.0.1:8090/
ProxyPassReverse /jenkins http://127.0.0.1:8090/
```

From what I understand about `ProxyPassReserve` is that it would rewrite the response header with `/jenkins/login` so that when the browser sends the redirected request again it would be `http://127.0.0.1:8090/jenkins/login`

Not sure if my understanding is correct or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add also:

```
ProxyPassReverse /jenkins http://123.45.67.89/
```

Probably on the ProxyPass you are maintaining the original host header (`ProxyPreserveHost On`), if so with this ProxyPassReverse probably will do the trick for you.

EDIT:

I've checked on my mini lab and the point is jenkins is not doing a redirection but it is giving you this html

```
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2F'/>
```

I solved it starting jenkins with switch `--prefix=/jenkins`

Comment: This is not working.

Comment: @tintin I've edited and changed the way to start jenkins (if possible for you)

Comment: I am starting jenkins as a service, so the prefix is getting ignored `sudo service jenkins start --prefix=/jenkins` Is there any way to pass the param?

Comment: Which OS? If RedHat/CentOS probably you have some files on /etc/sysconfig directory which allows you to change parameters for jenkins.